# Binary Search error in Finding Longest Substring of Repeating Characters

Tags: arrays, string, algorithm, c++14, binary-search

I have been doing a problem given as :

Given a string s, find the length of the longest substring without repeating characters.
e.g : Input: s = "pwwkew"
Output: 3 i.e. "wke" .

I implemented the code using c++. But it's giving a WA while running this testcase due to some error in using binarysearch in this problem . Here is my implementation of the code .

```
class Solution {
public:
    int lengthOfLongestSubstring(string s) {
        int n = s.size() ;
        vector<char> s1 ;
        int maxi = 0 ;
        
        for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
            if(binary_search(s1.begin(),s1.end(),s[i])){
                s1.clear();
                
                
            }
            
                s1.push_back(s[i]);
                int p = s1.size() ;
                maxi = max(maxi , p) ;
                
        }
        return maxi ;
        
    }
};
```

Here the code runs for all the cases properly but when the vector has [w,k,e] inside it , the binary_search fails to find w inside this array and the array is changed to [w,k,e,w] . Why is this happening ? I understand there is an optimal solution to this problem using sliding window . But what's the error in this implementation?

Comment: `binary_search` requires that the range to be searched is sorted. Your program passes a range to it that is not sorted, and thereby exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: ohh right , Gotcha !!!